# Is there anything like a create_view in ActiveRecord (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a view in my DB. I know I can use ActiveRecord to create tables with the create_table method. I wonder if there's anything alike create_table but that creates a view instead.

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://ideamotive.co/blog/materialized-views-ruby-rails-scenic/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. This is one of the things that ActiveRecord is ‘opinionated’ in. It doesn't really care much about common relational database features such as views, foreign keys, and some others.

The [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) contains a list of public methods available to you.

The best you can do is write the `CREATE`-statement in plain SQL, and use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`.

Comment: The downside is that these schema migrations with plain SQL are not detected when dumping the schema (unless you are using `db:structure:dump`, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the schema_plus gem to do this!

https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus

It's actually a group of gems but it contains one that pertains to views.

It provides a `create_view` method that you can add to your migrations and
it will dump the view into your schema.rb file so that it gets recreated if you do `rake db:schema:load`

More info here: https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus_views#user-content-creating-views

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Postgres, you can use [Scenic](https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic) to manage database views in your rails application. Like Schema Plus, Scenic will give you `create_view`. Unlike Schema Plus, Scenic will also provide a bit more guidance on managing versions of the view along with support for materialized views.

If you are using MySQL there are third-party mysql adapters available for use with Scenic, though I have not used them personally.